# Firefox blocking facebook-js-sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have a social registration flow on our site, but Firefox seems to be blocking the sdk scripts. I see they've basically white listed the facebook domain here (https://github.com/disconnectme/disconnect-tracking-protection/blob/master/entities.json).

I've read this too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Privacy/Tracking_Protection?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default

Screenshot of error in FF
[image]

But how can i.e Meetup.com(https://secure.meetup.com/login/) *still* run the facebook sdk script in FF without being affected? This indicates that it *should* be possible to still run facebook signin in FF.

Comment: have you use `crossorigin="anonymous"`?

Comment: @Muppet were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: @prof.phython this is an ongoing problem unfortunately

Comment: @Muppet We have decided to use manual login flow. Its working fine in our case. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

Comment: I do have the problem but I don't want to use the manual login flow. Anyone from Facebook can look into it?